# What are some alternatives to virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a lot of trouble lately installing on a box that i can't reboot or change the kernel. Is there any other package that supports gre tunnels (if the os supports ) that i can run on linux? Basically i want linux on linux. I can't yum upgrade or reboot.

Comment: By the way: this is related to your previous questions, right? I remember them because I read them a few minutes ago, but you need to recall all the relevant details in your question. In particular that you're running CentOS with a 2.6.18 kernel.

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia has a [comparison of platform virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines). If you want to use a stock 2.6.18 kernel, there aren't many options.

For full virtualization, [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) should work, but you may need to use older versions if their kernel module no longer supports such an old kernel. [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/) may be a possibility, but it was only included in the stock kernel as of 2.6.20, and I don't know how hard it is to get it running on 2.6.18. Another possibility is [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/); QEMU can be very slow because it fully emulates a processor rather than using the host processor's virtualization capabilities, but it doesn't need any low-level support on the host, it runs as a perfectly ordinary process.

There are many options for virtualizing Linux on Linux ([cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)/[LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lxc), [OpenVZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVZ), [VServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux-VServer)), but they require a custom or recent kernel. The one option that I think is suitable for you is [User-mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/). UML lets you run a Linux system as an unprivileged process on the host system. It has existed for a long time, so an old host kernel won't be a problem. It takes a bit of work to set up (there are howtos around), but after that it should provide what you need.

Comment: qemu-kvm actually uses vmx/svm VT extensions via a kernel module